# How to check if custom delegate was set?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, delegates

I've implemented a custom delegate, `RandomClassDelegate`, in `RandomClass.m` and `RandomClass.h`. Now I need to implement the delegate variable, and have it make calls to the methods in the protocol as follows:

```
[self.delegate randomClassDelegateMethod];
```

Obviously, if the `delegate` was never set, this is going to crash the program and cause a run time error. Obvious solution is to just do:

```
if (delegate)
{
[self.delegate randomClassDelegateMethod];
}
```

But I'm wondering if this is the correct pattern or if there is a better way to do this, maybe in the protocol or somewhere else?

Comment: Nope, if delegate was not set and is nil, you can still send any message to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `-respondsToSelector:` to check if the delegate is valid:

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myDelegateMethod)])
     [delegate myDelegateMethod];
```

Don't worry about checking for `nil`, as you can send a message to a nil object and it will do nothing.

Comment: Richard is correct. In Objective-c you can send messages to nil without consequence. This is correct and idiomatic usage. Because all instance variable object pointers are initialized to nil when an object is created, sending a message to an instance variables that hasn't yet been set is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the delegate if it is not empty and implemented.

```
if(delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(randomClassDelegateMethod)]) {
   [delegate randomClassDelegateMethod];
}
```

Comment: Its normally enough to check if it respondsToSelector. If its nil it also doesn't respond to any selector ;)